# How to dispose an object created by class FileInfo?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a

```
FileInfo
```

class to get the length of the file as follows:

```
FileInfo infoFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Text12341234");
long configFileLength = infoFile.Length;
```

I want to dispose the object created by

```
FileInfo
```

class.
I am getting an error that "File has been already in use by another process."
How can i do this?

Comment: How did you dispose? I see no code of that.

Comment: This issue is not caused by `FileInfo`; the code you posted doesn't create the file.

Comment: I am creating my file as follows:

Comment: File.Create(Application.StartupPath + @"\Client.config.xml");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FileInfo` does not implement `IDisposable`, hence you can't dispose it.

Any results from other methods you call on `FileInfo` which do implement `IDisposable` must be dealt with on the actual object, not on `FileInfo`.

You should use `using`:

```
using (FileStream s = File.Create(Application.StartupPath + @"\Client.config.xml"))
{
    // your code using s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileInfo` doesn't open a stream.If you used methods like `OpenRead` you need to close the `Stream` you opened by calling `Close` method.Or simply wrap your statement with `using`.

Comment: preferable using should be used where IDisposable is implemented. In case of Exceptions you don't need to have a finally block, where you call the close.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problems running, no need to dispose; I think this piece of code will help you:

```
var f = new FileInfo(@"d:\ntt.txt");
var fs = f.Create();

// you can use dispose here, for it returns filestream
fs.Dispose();
```

Comment: If at all possible do use `using` pattern, that way it is properly disposed in case of exceptions, and makes it easier to write readable code.